# How to convert name in method in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I would like to convert a method type name, (I don't know if it's a good term)

I have this

```
public static getPrices(): IPrice[] {
    const prices = [

      {
        id: Faker.random.uuid(),
        name: "Cours à l'unité",
        amount: 990,
        capacity: 1,
        type: "community",
},
     {
        id: Faker.random.uuid(),
        name: "Cours en petit groupe",
        amount: 2000,
        capacity: 1,
        type: "smallGroup",
      },
]}
```

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Acheter{lesson !== null ? ` cours ${lesson.type}` : ""}</Text>
</View>
```

I would like to convert "community" to "Community course" and "smallGroup" to "Small groupe course" it is possible ?

Comment: What's stopping you from just changing the string? Do you get an error when you try and change `       type: "community",` to `       type: "Community cours",`?

Comment: It's because I would like to keep "community"

Comment: I think I am misunderstanding something. In the original question you say you would like to convert it, but you would also like to keep it?

If you do not want to interfere with what you have now you could have another object/dictionary with the readable text version as the value and use the type as a key to do a look up.

Or a simpler approach - add another property called `typeText: "Community course"`

Comment: Thanks, yes i would like to keep  "community" and I would like to do something like  "community" : "Community course", but I don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple object mapping the types to strings should be enough.

```
const typesMap = {
    community: 'Community course',
    smallGroup: 'Small group course'
}
```

And then use it like this

```
<Text>Acheter{lesson !== null ? ` cours ${typesMap[lesson.type]}` : ""}</Text>
```

This way you would have both the string and the original type value. Using a translation lib like [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) in the same way would be even better, depending on size of the app.